# Load all dozer xml files in a directory

Tags: java, file, directory, dozer

In Dozer  we can inject XML custom mapping files to Dozer via  **setMappingFiles** function.

```
List myMappingFiles = new ArrayList();
myMappingFiles.add("dozerBeanMapping.xml");
myMappingFiles.add("someOtherDozerBeanMappings.xml"); DozerBeanMapper
mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.setMappingFiles(myMappingFiles);
```

but i have 100 XML files in a directory in resources Classpath folder.
what is best solution for inject them into Dozer?

**I try this in spring5:**

```
  @Value("classpath*:dozer/*.xml")
  private Resource[] resources;

  @Bean(name = "org.dozer.Mapper")
  public DozerBeanMapper dozerBean() {
    DozerBeanMapper dozerBean = new DozerBeanMapper();
    dozerBean.setMappingFiles(resources); //this is wrong
    return dozerBean;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't identify in [`DozerBeanMapper`](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dozer/DozerBeanMapper.html) a method that provides such a way.

As workaround : map the resources to a `List<String>` and you could so use `DozerBeanMapper.setMappingFiles(List<String> mappingFileUrls)`.
Note that you can inject `List<Resources>`  instead of `Resource[]` that is more handy.

```
@Value("classpath*:dozer/*.xml")
private List<Resources> resources;

@Bean(name = "org.dozer.Mapper")
public DozerBeanMapper dozerBean() {
   List<String> xmlString = 
           resources.stream()
                    .map(t -> {
                                try {
                                      return t.getFile().toURI().toURL().toString();   
                                    }
                                    catch (IOException e) {
                                      throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                    }
                        })  
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

    DozerBeanMapper dozerBean = new DozerBeanMapper();
    dozerBean.setMappingFiles(xmlString );
    return dozerBean;
}
```

Comment: getFile() return File handler and file.toString() get system path of xml files. but dozer.setMappingFile() get class path and therefore throw "org.dozer.MappingException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c" error

Comment: I didn't use this dozer method before but its refers to a URL in the javadoc. So you could try something as : t.getFile().toURI().toURL().toString(); to provide a String version of the URL.